# Apple App Site Association File Parsing Error

Tags: ios

We're trying to get universal links working in our app but we are encountering errors when trying to download the Apple App Site Association file.

We've used various online tools to validate the file and they all say their is a parsing error but they don't go into any detail about what the issue is.

We've validated that the JSON is valid but what else could be wrong with the file contents?

```
{
  "applinks": {
      "details": [
           {
             "appIDs": [ "12345NGB.co.uk.my.app" ],
             "components": [
               {
                  "/": "/universallink/*",
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /universallink/"
               }
             ]
           }
       ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Please see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html Your JSON is valid, but doesn't match the expected structure

Comment: Isn't that format supposed to be prior to iOS 13?: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains_in_your_app#3001215

Answer (score 0):

It turns the I did need to follow the format outlined here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [{
      "appID": "12345NGB.co.uk.my.app",
      "paths": ["/universallink/*"]
    }]
  }
}
```

The Apple documentation is very misleading because it suggests that's an old format for supporting iOS 12 and earlier.